# IRQB on W65C22 unstable

Tags: integrated-circuit, interrupts

I am following the YouTube tutorials by Ben Eater to build a 6502 computer (https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLowKtXNTBypFbtuVMUVXNR0z1mu7dp7eH). I got everything to work until the part with the interrupt handling using the W65C22 Versatile Interface Adapter.

For some reason my W65C22 chip keeps triggering interrupts. I measured the output voltage of the IRQB pin and found it is always about 1.5 V. I don't know if it keeps switching between high and low very rapidly and my multimeter just measures this value as an average, or whether it actually stays constant at this level.

I checked the datasheet and found this paragraph below, and I only understand about half of this. But it does talk about some difference between the W65C22N and W65C22S. And I realized I got the W65C22N version while Ben Eater is using the W65C22S in his videos.

> The IRQB output signal is logic 0 whenever an internal Interrupt Flag bit is set to logic 1 and the
> corresponding Interrupt Enable bit is logic 1. The IRQB output is a full output driver that outputs both logic 1
> and logic 0 levels. The W65C22N and older NMOS and CMOS IRQB output is/was an open drain pull
> down only, thus allowing the IRQB signal to be wire ORed with an external resistor for a common
> microprocessor IRQB input line. The W65C22S IRQB can be wire ORed with a pull down diode that is
> forward biased when IRQB is low. See Figure 3.4 IRQB for the IRQB buffer schematics for both the
> W65C22N and W65C22S.
>
> The IRQB pin on the W65C22S is a standard totem pole output. The W65C22S IRQB signal was meant for
> logically ORing rather than wire ORing the IRQ’s of a system. This change was made to improve the low
> power, high speed characteristics of the part. For systems that have wire ORed IRQB outputs a solution is to
> place a low voltage diode (<0.5V) in series with the W65C22S totem pole IRQB output.

[image]

(Page 31, of this [datasheet](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/436/w65c22-1197.pdf))

Does this explain the behavior of my chip? What do I need to do, to get it working properly?

Comment: You need a pullup resistor (to +5 V). A value of 4.7k would supply about 1 mA in the low state, which should be about right.

Comment: You also need to get an oscilloscope so that you can see the details of the behavior of signals at speed. For the 6502, anything with a bandwidth of at least 10 - 20 MHz would be plenty.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thank you, that worked. Could someone explain a bit more detailed what the datasheet is trying to tell me?